# Using phpMailer to send contact form over Gmail

Tags: php

I am a beginning web designer/dev and I am currently trying to fix a contact form for a website. The website was created awhile ago and the contact form is broken. I am doing my best just to fix the contact form and not change anything else, but I am having a really hard time doing so.

All of the files that I thought would be html files, all end in .asp, rather than .html. So, I had heard that you can send mail using PHP, so I downloaded a tutorial (I actually looked at around 30 different tutorials to find one that was any good), and figured that I got it working. I did not.

My goal was to send a information from the form, to the php file, to my gmail, then off to my client. This was all using **phpMailer**. I had phpMailer in the same folder on the server that my php file and the contact form was in; ya know, so they could see each other. But, I cannot get this thing to work. I keep getting a 500 server error.

PHP is enabled on the server, and php mail is not being blocked.

I there something wrong with my code? Or is it a server thing that I am not aware of. At any rate, I am very confused and frustrated.

**The .asp file which contains the html form**

```
<form method="post" action="contact_form.php">
             <p>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="txt" id="name" size="30" />
            </p>
             <p>
                <label for="company">Company:</label>
                <input name="company" type="text" class="txt" id="company" size="30" />
             </p>
              <p>
                <label for="city">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="txt" />
              </p>
             <p>
                <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                <textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="5" class="txtarea" id="comments"></textarea>
             </p>
             <p>
                <label for="blank">&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn" value="Send"/>
             </p>
    </form>
```

**The code for the php file that sends the email**

```
<?php

$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$site_owners_email = 'support@macnx.com'; // Replace this with your own email address
$site_owners_name = 'Landin'; // replace with your name

if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name";  
}

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
}

if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
    $error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
}

if (!$error) {

    require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Subject = "Website Contact Form";
    $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
    $mail->Body = $company, $comments;

    // GMAIL STUFF

    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "inquiry@getgearhead.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "B******A"; // SMTP password

    $mail->Send();

    echo "<li class='success'> Congratulations, " . $name . ". We've received your email. We'll be in touch as soon as we possibly can! </li>";

} # end if no error
else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<li>" . $error['name'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<li>" . $error['email'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<li>" . $error['comments'] . "</li>" : null;

    echo $response;
} # end if there was an error sending

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!


**EDIT:**

I got the email to send, there was a syntax error, it was fixed.

Although, after the email sends it still gives me a 500 server error, even though the email sent correctly. It has something to to do with the echo response at the bottom of the .php.

```
echo "<li class='success'> Congratulations, " . $name . ". We've received your email. We'll be in touch as soon as we possibly can! </li>";

} # end if no error
else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<li>" . $error['name'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<li>" . $error['email'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<li>" . $error['comments'] . "</li>" : null;

    echo $response;
} # end if there was an error sending
```

Like I said before, I got this from a tutorial, and the guy was using all kinds of javascript and css, i tried to ignore most of it, so therefore some of my code is not accurate.

Is there a better way to tell the person submitting information that the email has been sent? I just need it to go to a separate page, or show it somewhere, all it does right now is give a 500 service error.

Thanks.

Comment: enable all logs in the server

Comment: Why do you mix .php with .asp ? A error 500 means 'Internal server error'. Does php work on this server ? Maybe there is a general misconfiguraton for php. Only the error log of the server can give you the answer.

Comment: PHP is enabled, and the mail function is not blocked. And yeah, that is what I was thinking, I will just need to look at the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be broken:

```
$mail->Body = $company, $comments;
```

Perhaps you want to say

```
$mail->Body = $company . $comments;
```

Comment: Would this cause the whole thing to give a server error? Sorry if that is a dumb question lol

Comment: It is a php syntax error, so yes, this would cause a server 500 error.

Comment: Well, after I fixed that then reuploaded it, it still gave me a 500 error, but it took a lot longer to do so. So it seems that it got past the contact_form.php, but then errored.

Comment: Do you have any php errors in the log or anywhere else? Or any server logs?

Comment: OH! it worked! my client just called at said that he received the message! But, I still got the error. Could it be in the response part of the PHP file? That part was from the tutorial and I don't know much about it.

Comment: So would that look like:

Comment: Hmm, is there a way that I can rewrite the whole response bit. I don't want it to do anything but display that is sent. Is there just a common or easy way to just say, it sent, without worrying if there was an error not.

Comment: Yes, I am still getting the 500 error after I hit submit, although the email is sending though.

Comment: For reference, the website is www.macnx.com/noflash/contact.asp